# Mapping JSON data in Spring MVC using Jackson parser

Tags: ajax, post, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-3

Client code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../web/zittles",
        data: jsonformatdata,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
        {
        alert("data from server : "+data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("jqXHR.status = "+jqXHR.status); //getting status code 400 here
        }        
});
```

Output json data:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "No": "1234",
        "Desc": "Testing"
}
```

Java class:

```
public class Fizzle implements Serializable
{
    private String id;
    private String No;
    private String Desc;
    // getters and setters 
}
```

Spring 3 Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/zittles', method = RequestMethod.POST, headers ="Content-Type=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody void doSomeThing (@RequestBody Fizzle fizzle) {

        //do something here
}
```

app-servlet.xml has

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

/lib folder of tomcat has

```
jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.10.jar
jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.10.jar
```

Getting error with status code 400 -

```
"The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"
```

When I change the Controller code as shown below, it takes the json data as string.

```
public @ResponseBody void doSomeThing (@RequestBody String fizzle) {}
```

Ideally Jackson should automatically map the json data to Fizzle object.

What is it that I am missing here. Is there anything else that has to be done to configure the Jackson parser correctly?

Help please.

Comment: @RequestBody dumps the body in that variable, remove it and it should work i think.

Comment: he wants to convert input json to POJO, so @RequestBody is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question since it worked for me. Thanks "vacuum" for giving me the direction. I am using List since I am receving an array of json data.

```
@JsonTypeName
@RequestMapping(value = '/zittles', method = RequestMethod.POST, headers ="Content-Type=application/json")     
public @ResponseBody void doSomeThing (@RequestBody String fizzles) 
{          
     //do something here
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     ArrayList list = mapper.readValue(new StringReader(fizzles), ArrayList.class);
     List<Fizzle> fizzles1 = mapper.convertValue(list, new TypeReference<List<Fizzle>>() {});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Id must be long or int, not a String

```
 private int id;
```

**Edit**

Maybe try this JSON:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "no": "1234",
        "desc": "Testing"
}
```

and change properties to lowercase in Fizzle class

**Edit2**
Test if this is Jakson issue or Spring issue.
Save your JSON to file and try to convert it to object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Fizzle fizzle = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\fizzle.json"), Fizzle .class);
```

Comment: Even changing the properties to lowercase did not work. This is really frustating. As I said in my post, it works when I accept the json data as String. Is there a way I can manually map this json String into my Fizzle object?